# Getting The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, routes, apache2

I have followed the base project structure from https://github.com/crjoseabraham/php-mvc
Using that, I have created a php MVC project that works fine on the development server AWS EC2. I am facing a redirection issue after binding a domain.

I have applied the below changes in my Apache2.conf for a binding domain.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName subdomain.mydomain.com
    ServerAlias www.subdomain.mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/project-1/public
    <Directory /var/www/html/project-1/public>

        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/subdomain.mydomain.com_error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/subdomain.mydomain.com_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

My project Structure :

[image]

The root directory .htaccess file has the below code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^$ public/ [L]
    RewriteRule (.*) public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

And the public directory .htaccess code is :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        Options -Multiviews
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /project-1/public
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   
    RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
 
</IfModule>
```

So, after applying the above changes, I am able to access my project using the domain name and it opens the landing page successfully. But when I click on menu then I am getting the error :

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was
> unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator at [no address given] to
> inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you
> performed just before this error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
> log.

To resolve this issue, I have applied many changes in a public .htaccess file but was unable to solve it. So, can you please help me to resolve this issue?

Here are changes that I have tried :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase //

    
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Apache error log :

AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace., referer: http://subdomain.mydomain.com/

Comment: A 500 Internal Server Error is a generic error message and covers pretty much every single thing that can go wrong with a PHP script. Check your server error logs to find out the exact error message.

Comment: It's not a PHP script-related error.  It's an apache configuration-related error. I have added an error in my question get from the Apache error log. Please check it.

Comment: This `RewriteRule (.*) public/$1 [L]` looks like a redirect loop.  Anything that starts with 'public/' is also going to match this rule, and be redirected, etc

Comment: This too `RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]` is going to cause a similar problem.  Perhaps remove the `,L`?

Comment: Apache supports enabling debugging so that you can diagnose which rules are causing the 10x internal redirects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> DocumentRoot /var/www/html/project-1/public
> ```

Since you have set the `DocumentRoot` to point directly at the `public` subdirectory then you should remove the first `.htaccess` file completely (the one you have called "The root directory .htaccess file" - but it's not "the root", it's in the directory *above* the root!)

Then you only need a single `.htaccess` file inside the `public` directory (which is "the root") and **remove the `RewriteBase` directive** entirely (which you had set incorrectly and would have resulted in a rewrite loop - 500 error).

For example:

```
# The public (root) directory .htaccess file

Options -MultiViews

DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f   
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

The `<IfModule>` wrapper should also be removed.

The relative substitution string rewrites the request relative to the directory that contains the `.htaccess` file. No need for `RewriteBase` here.

Comment: Thanks for the detail explanation. I have applied changes in the public .htaccess file as per your answer but still it is not working. Should I need to remove the root .htaccess file?

Comment: @Hkachhia Yes, you need to remove the parent `.htaccess` file (as mentioned above). You have called it the "root `.htaccess` file", but it's not in the root, it is "above" the document root. That `.htaccess` file rewrites requests to the `public` subdirectory, but since you have defined the `DocumentRoot` (in the server coinfig) to point directly at the `public` subdirectory it is not required. (Presumably you restarted Apache after making changes to the server config?)

Comment: I have deleted the parent .htaccess file but still it is not working. When I print URL in my routes page then it removes the folder name from the URL e.g subdomain.mydomain.com/land/sites/getAllList but when I print it display only \Controllers\Sites. Where in localhost it is printing whole path \Controllers\Land\Sites

Comment: After updating the public .htaccess file CSS, js not loading

Comment: I have resolved the issue. It is not related to .htaccess but issue in the route file. Thanks